# Align single column in table row android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to align row in table layout pragmatically, but the last column where i have image button keep stretching, I tried padding and setColumnStretchable to false but no luck so far. Below is my code and app UI...

[image].

```
 TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.scrollViewTable);
    tl.setColumnStretchable(1,true);
    tl.setColumnStretchable(2,true);
    tl.setColumnStretchable(3,true);
    tl.setColumnStretchable(4,false);
    /* Create a new row to be added. */
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    /* Create a Button to be the row-content. */
    TextView prodName = new TextView(this);
    TextView unitPrice = new TextView(this);
    TextView Quantity = new TextView(this);
    TextView total = new TextView(this);
    Button remove = new Button(this);

    prodName.setText(productDetails.getText());
    unitPrice.setText(price.getText());
    Quantity.setText(sellQuantity.getText());
    total.setText("890");
    remove.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.delete);
    prodName.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    prodName.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    unitPrice.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    unitPrice.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    Quantity.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    Quantity.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    remove.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    remove.setPadding(1,1,1,1);
    /* Add Button to row. */
        tr.addView(prodName);
    tr.addView(unitPrice);
    tr.addView(Quantity);
    tr.addView(remove);

    /* Add row to TableLayout. */
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solution but its not really that clean the Button still doesn't look perfect aligned. Let me know if you know any better way to manage this..

[image]

```
Replace Line
remove.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    remove.setPadding(1,1,1,1);

Added this
remove.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,0f));
```